# None of my code appears in Golang memory profiler output

Tags: go, profiling, memory-profiling

I'm currently working on a Go program that loads data from a database, runs some calculations and then saves the results to the same database. There are multiple gorutines.

The runtime (5-6 minutes) was surprisingly long. Following this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs) I performed CPU profiling and it turns out that 70%+ of the CPU time is Garbage Collection related code running.

Now, I tried memory profiling but none of my my code appears in the results. This is my first time profiling a program - I don't know how to proceed with optimisation of the program or where to look for problems. I appreciate any help.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, try sorting by cumulative instead of flat. That should give you an indication of what code of yours is calling stdlib code that is allocating memory. You can use e.g. `top10 -cum` to give you the top 10 cumulative memory users.

Comment: Silly me.... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by Adrian, the 'problem' is simply solved by sorting by cumulative instead of flat, for example using `top10 -cum`